# How to achieve a drawable shape with curved corners

Tags: android, android-drawable

Please how can I achieve the image below as background for an image view.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Create `my_shape.xml` under `res/drawable`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#A5A5A5" />
            <corners
                android:bottomRightRadius="75dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="100dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Then, you can apply it to your view with:

`android:background="@drawable/my_shape"`

Comment: Yeah I did this but when the image appear the background is gone.

Comment: Do you set it to an ImageView with background, and also have another image set to this ImageView .. can you elaborate more?

Comment: i suppose he wants the shape to be only pattern of the image am I right?

Comment: @user9977151 I guess that also, maybe they need it in the background while the image can have some opacity

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-with-rounded-corners ?